# Program running from a folder where a parent folder is not accessible wont be able to use tcp layer

Tags: windows-7, tcp

This issue is one that has taken me and our IT department at our company many hours to pinpoint.

The problem only appears on Windows server 2008, windows 7 and windows 8. On Windows XP or Windows server 2003 we have no issues.

We are having a program that we have developed internally in our company. The program works fine and the issue is not specific to this program.

The program uses localhost to communicate with other programs running on the computer using webservices. The issue at hand is that this communication doesn't work if the program is located in the users Home folder.

Having used many hours finding out why this is we recently realized that problem disappears if the user has access to all parent folder in the UNC path to the executable file.

So if the home drive is mounted at H: = \SomeServer\hdrive$\SomeUser
and the user has no acces to \SomeServer\hdrive$ then our program gets TCP errors and the webservices wont work.

If the user then gets just the "List folder contents" permission on that path, then the webservices work.

The program otherwise runs fine.
We have checked that all dll files are linked successfully and that no other errors occurs.

This appears to be something that the OS is doing.
Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: This is a permission problem flat and simple.

Comment: Yes. I agree. 
But how do you fix this issue without giving all users in the company access to the root of the home drive?

Comment: I'm sure ot has something to do with the Local Security Authority (LSA). But which control is determining this behavior?

Comment: How is only listing the contents of a direcotry without the ability to open or write the files a security concern?  The alternative is to create a new home directory that you can list the contents of.

Comment: Yes and why does this influence the ability to use the network?

Comment: Try it yourself. This is pretty easy to reproduce.

Comment: I have no idea what the webservice does exactly. Its possible what is being done is being done in a non-standard way. I don't see how only listing the contents of `hdrive$` is a security concern.

Comment: I am as lost as you are on this issue. I have no idea why Windows would do this. As i've said the issue is not specific to the programs that we have developed. Just create a simple webservice server and client that are using localhost to communicate. run the client from a folder as described above, and you will see the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 7 and up, certain folders are protected by default. My understanding is that this is for security reasons. ie. It makes it harder for program A to secretly modify a dll used by program B.

Often, I've found that if I right-click on the program in question, and run "as administrator" it will work just fine. I'm not sure that would work in your case.

Comment: I tried running as administrator. But it doesn't appear to change this behavior.

Comment: By the way. The folder in question is a mapped network drive. Not a path on the local machine.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the OS doesn't protect and network shared folders by default.